# Redux Store. Хранить результат вычислений или полученные начальные данные?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Как лучше всего хранить данные в Redux Store, те которые мы получили из API сырые данные или уже вычисленные, необходимые для вывода данные?

Например, на странице выводятся в отдельных компонентах три значения **Значение1**, **Значение2**, **Значение3**.
Эти значения являются вычисляемыми, т.е. для каждого из этих значений для их вычисления происходит по несколько своих API запросов для получения необходимых данных. Т.е.

Значение1 - данные запроса 1(например, массив [{id: 1, count: 1, amount: 100, ...}]) count=1, данные  запроса 2 которые зависят от запроса 1.

Значение2 - данные запроса 1(например, массив [{id: 1, count: 1, amount: 100, ...}]) amount = 100, данные запроса 3

Значение3 - данные запроса 4.

В дополнение ко всему Node.js присылает еще извещения о изменившихся данных. Т.е. приходит событие, что в данных изменился элемент с id=1, и сами эти данные: {id: 1, count: 2, amount: 100, ...}. После чего и необходимо перевычислить **Значение1** и **Значение2**, т.к. изменился элемент с id=1

Как все же лучше организовывать, ведь в случае с уже вычисленными значениями мы имеем очень простые компоненты привязанные к redux store:

```
class Container1 extends Component {
  render() {
    let { value1 } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {value1}
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}
connect(function(state) {
  return {
    value1: state.value1
  }
}
)(Container1)
```

Но вот как в этом случае контролировать изменившиеся данные? Перевычилять и **Значение1**  и **Значение2**, и в случае изменения, только тогда делать dispatch с новым вычисленным значением? Ведь если бы были сырые данные тогда я бы сделал изменение массива и значения бы сами перевычислились, здесь я имею ввиду:

```
class Container1 extends Component {
  render() {
    let { fetchedData1, fetchedData2} = this.props;
    let value1 = Service.calculateValue1(fetchedData1, fetchedData2);

    return (
      <div>
        {value1}
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}
connect(function(state) {
  return {
    fetchedData1: state.fetchedData1,
    fetchedData2: state.fetchedData2
  }
}
)(Container1)
```

Первый вариант смотрится конечно более привлекательнее, но вот как его организовывать, как контролировать изменения в сырых данных, чтобы вычислять только нужные значения и класть в redux store?

Comment: Я бы не удивился если бы кто-то Вас понял, но лично мне кажется что Вы либо вообще не в курсе что такое redux, либо наоборот в курсе и просто решили подшутить над всеми. Если первое, то начните с малого и почитайте статьи, коих просто дофигище чтобы понять что же такое redux, а затем документация. Ваш вопрос звучит как - что нужно сделать чтобы у слона появился хобот.

Comment: @OlmerDale Не могли бы Вы пояснить подробнее, что в вопросе Вас смущет?

Comment: Вы спрашивает как сделать то, за что хвалят и для чего создан redux. Если я правильно понял, то Вы спрашиваете как обновлять состояние приложения. Но если я правильно понял это, то я значит прав и в первом комментарии.

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел код и могу сказать что компоненты не должны производить какие-то вычисления над данными, которые они получают. Еще можно представить что в свободном стиле программирования на redux, какие-то расчеты над внутреннем состоянием самого компонента, а не данных, могут производится в самом компоненте, но не более.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но, здесь я не могу понять, как контролировать эти вычисляемые значения? Например, для вычисления Значения1 мне необходимы данные из запроса 1 (data1: [{id:1, count:1}, ...]) и запроса 2(data2). Я вычислил Занчение1 = calculate(data1, data2). Далее мне приходит событие, что изменился объект с id=1, и приходит сам этот объект: {id:1, count:2}. Далее мне нужно пересчитать Значение1, но уже с измененным значением id=1 в data1. Это простой пример. Но вот что делать если еще некоторые значения зависят от этого самого id=1. Для каждого значения запоминать, что он зависит от id=1?

Comment: Вам нужно почитать документацию и точка! Вы просите не дать совет, а пересказать всю документацию! Ладно несколько лет назад не было на русском, это ещё можно было понять, но сейчас тысячу статей объясняющие как это сделать и написаны вполне доходчиво. Поэтому не теряйте время читайте основы, чем быстрее Вы их поймете, тем быстрее сможете сделать.

Comment: @OlmerDale К сожалению, мы друг друга не понимаем. Я не прошу Вас пересказывать документацию. Если следовать Вашей логике, то вообще не стоит задавать вопросов. Но все равно спасибо.

Comment: К сожалению Вы на все мои попытки послать Вас читать доки, так ни разу и не ответили что уже ОБЧИТАЛИСЬ их. Это означает что Вы хотите чтобы Вам рассказали то что написано в доках. Если следовать Вашей логике, то читать книги вообще нафиг не нужно, ведь есть подобные форумы, где люди которым вообще нифига делать сидят и сутками переписывают каждый день одни и те же главы из прочитанных книг. 
Как можно браться за изучение подобного не читая? реакт многие не любят из-за его заумного комуните, которое состоит из математиков и Вы, не любитель читать, взялись за его изучение.

Comment: И если Вы так не поймете, то обычно тут спрашивают как изменить массив или что-то подобное. Но чтобы Вам сделать минимальный пример, нужно написать целое приложение, пусть и совсем минимально. Поэтому тут даже сравнивать нечего. Отправляйтесь читать. Или скажите, что именно Вам не понятно из офф документации? опишите проблему профессиональным языком redux.

Comment: @OlmerDale набросал jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wb4z19sx/

Comment: @OlmerDale т.е. меня интересует как контролировать value1, value2 value3, в зависимости от какого-то измененного элемента.Т.е. как это грамотно организовать? Огромный код мне писать не нужно, мне нужно, чтобы мне посоветовали грамотный подход для этого